# Regarding times

Tags: sql, count

I have a resultset

```
ID  Datetime                MID EID     Serial     ELapsed_time
0   2014-08-11 19:56:20.923 8A  6147    70          123
0   2014-08-12 00:17:06.090 8A  6147    71          261
0   2014-08-12 01:11:25.833 8A  6368    72           54
0   2014-08-12 02:36:40.710 8A  6147    73           85
0   2014-08-12 09:09:15.400 8A  0861    74          393
0   2014-08-12 11:27:21.870 8A  0861    75          138
0   2014-08-12 16:32:10.680 8A  0861    76          305
0   2014-08-12 20:37:16.767 8A  4273    78          245
0   2014-08-12 22:39:49.740 8A  4273    79          122
```

My requirement is to fill a table with Starttime, EndTime, EIDCOUNT

For example,

Startime of the newtable should be 2014-08-11 19:56:20.923 and end time should be 2014-08-12 00:17:06.090
and EIDCOUNT is 1

and the next row, starttime should be 2014-08-12 00:17:06.090 and end time is 2014-08-12 01:11:25.833
and EIDCOUNT is 1

and the next row, startime should be 2014-08-12 01:11:25.833 and endtime is 2014-08-12 02:36:40.710
and EIDCOUNT is 1

and the next row, starttime should be 2014-08-12 02:36:40.710 and endtime is 2014-08-12 16:32:10.680
and EIDCOUNT is 3

and the next row, starttime should be 2014-08-12 16:32:10.680 and endtime is 2014-08-12 22:39:49.740 and EIDCOUNT is 2

```
StartTime                       EndTime              EIDCOUNT
2014-08-11 19:56:20.923    2014-08-12 00:17:06.090         1
2014-08-12 00:17:06.090    2014-08-12 01:11:25.833         1
2014-08-12 01:11:25.833    2014-08-12 02:36:40.710         1
2014-08-12 02:36:40.710    2014-08-12 16:32:10.680         3
2014-08-12 16:32:10.680    2014-08-12 22:39:49.740         2
```

Please help.

Comment: So what exactly do you want?

Comment: C.J. For the eID '6368', the starttime should be the previous Datetime for previous eID '6147', if there are eID's in a row, lets say '0861' then the previous eID for this is '6147', the datetime for this is 2014-08-12 02:36:40.710, this should be the starttime but ends with where the eid ends the repetition, i.e, at datetime 2014-08-12 16:32:10.680 and hence the count should be 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable(StartTime, EndTime, EIDCOUNT)
SELECT MIN(DateTime), MAX(DateTime), COUNT(*)
FROM SourceTable
GROUP BY EID
```

Your source data only has four distinct EID values (0861, 4273, 6147, 6368), so it looks like your EIDCOUNTs should be 3, 2, 3, and 1.

Comment: But the starttime, endtime messes up.

I want the resultset like i mentioned in the description.

For the eID '6368', the starttime should be the previous Datetime for previous eID '6147', if there are eID's in a row, lets say '0861' then the previous eID for this is '6147', the datetime for this is 2014-08-12 02:36:40.710, this should be the starttime but ends with where the eid ends the repetition, i.e, at datetime 2014-08-12 16:32:10.680 and hence the count should be 3.

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but that will make the first entry (EID 6147) inconsistent, since there is no previous DateTime before 2014-08-11 19:56:20.923 to use.

Comment: I added the first record manually. Is there a way we can get the resultset (no need of 100%) just want the approach.

Comment: SQL may not be the best language for this. It sounds like you need to iterate through the table in Serial order and start counting whenever EID changes, even if it's an EID value that has been previously used. You'll also have to decide what to do when you reach DateTime.Now(). Stop counting and output a record? What if the next record has the same EID? I would suggest trying to solve this in whatever procedural language you're using.